# JSR303 : Is it possible to inject arguments to a custom validator at validation time?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a custom validator and it need to know the user being validated. How to inject the User object in a custom validator ?

After some search it seems there is no way to do that, maybe it's something no applicable to jsr 303 ?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the framework you're using to perform dependency injection and object wiring.

The Spring framework provides out-of-the-box support for dependency injection within validators since version 3.0. Have a look at the [reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring) to learn how to use `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`.

If you're using CDI, then you might be interested in [Seam Validation](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/ValidationModule), a CDI portable injection which provides dependency injection for validators using CDI.

If that not answers your question, an example showing what you're up to do would help.